# Using External CSS on a PHP file

Tags: php, css

I haven't used CSS before for a PHP file and from what I read online, it is called by using this if my css filed is named "style.css":

`<head><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"></head>`

Now the header I used for my php files was this:

```
<style type="text/css">
    body {background-color: #FFFFbd}
</style>
<title>Order Information DB</title>
<center><font size="18">
    Order Information<br>
</font></center>

<center>
<img src="MacDonaldLogoSmall.png" alt = "bulls logo">

</center>
        <center><p> 

            <a href="SeniorDB_Customer.php">Customer DB</a>
            -
            <a href="SeniorDB_Invoice.php">Invoice DB</a>
            -
            <a href="SeniorDB_Order.php">Order DB</a>
            -
            <a href="SeniorDB_Product.php">Product DB</a>
            -
            <a href="SeniorDB_Shipping.php">Shipping DB</a>
        </p>
    </center>
    <HR size="7" color="green">

    <center><div style="position: absolute; bottom: 5px;">
    </div>
</div>
</style>
```

So when I moved this to my `style.css` file, it doesn't transfer over. Can anyone explain why? I"m very new to CSS.

Comment: what exactly did you move to your .css file? because all i see is one line which can do into it (a second if you make your inline `style` a class). also make sure that you've wiped out the browser's cache because more often than not CSS changes not being applied after reloading a page can normally be [blamed on the cache](http://shouldiblamecaching.com/)

Comment: You need to find where in your application your <head> tag is being output and put it there. Although it should work find if you just add this anywhere: `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">` Note that this assumes your css file is in the same directory as php file your currently accessing. If you add a / to the front of the href then it will look for style.css in the root of your site. You may need something like this `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/resources/css/style.css">`

Comment: @Memor-X I was wondering if I can move the entire code over. Image / buttons / etc. I know it's usually just a style thing, but is it possible to transfer everything from the header?

Comment: @AntonyThompson It is in the same folder as the php file

Comment: Please note that you have problems in your markup. And I'm not talking about those elderly elements that should have retired long ago. I mean, I presume `center` and `font` still work in modern day browsers (although I'm not sure; haven't used them in a couple of decades). I'm talking about `<font size="18">`. That's an error; size only goes up to 7. And there's a `</style>` at the end, which is also an error.

Comment: Anyway, you seem to think that all this you posted is CSS. It isn't. So like @Memor-X says, only the `body {background-color: #FFFFbd}` can go into the stylesheet. The rest is HTML, and parts of it belong in the head, other parts in the body.

Comment: @MrLister I see. I was under the impression  I can transfer everything over. I didn't want JUST to background / font / color /etc. I also wanted each page to have the buttons / logo / authentication / logout.